# Web service using Lotus notes

Tags: web-services, lotus-notes

when am trying to WSDL using lotus script i got following error, any one help me

"Error: client:WSDLreader:Loading of the wsdl file failed HRESULT=0x80070057-WSDLReader:xml Parser failed at linenumber 1, lineposition 63, reason is required white space was missing.HRESULT=0x1Line:7"

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like an error with the WSDL file. See if you can verify it with an online WSDL checker.

Also, make sure you have specified the correct endpoint URL.

Comment: Thanks, and endpoint url was correct, will you tell me how can I verify it with an online WSDL checker?.

Comment: Use Google to find one and then upload your WSDL.

Comment: "http://server.local/inclued/Aanandaprabhu/sampledb.nsf/wspTest?WSDL" here "wspTest" is webservice consumer name. Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

That error normally means that the structure of the WSDL is broken. For example if you got a 404 page back instead of WSDL from the server.

First try opening the WSDL File via a browser and check it to make sure you only get the WSDL back.

Your URL above has at the end:

```
?WSDL%22
```

The %22 looks wrong.

Second you can test your WSDL using a tool like SOAPUI. http://www.soapui.org

There is a tutorial on the Wiki at this location:

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Testing_your_Domino_web_service_provider_and_consumer_using_SoapUI._